# Информация о технической поддержке PHP

Tags: обсуждение, метки, описание-метки

Сегодня в очередной раз [правили подробное описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/315672) [метки PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), меняли циферки, проставляли даты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я смотрю на эту всю движуху вокруг и думаю: а оно нам надо эту информацию переписывать с оф.сайтов, следить за актуальностью с точностью до минорных версий, дат выпуска или достаточно просто дать ссылку и не заниматься постоянно мониторингом подобной информации?

Может быть оставить ссылку и этого будет вполне достаточно?

Comment: Интересно, кто-нибудь вообще полное описание читает?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, как минимум, ту, кто правит

Answer (score 7):

Подходить нужно от вредного. Единственный минус таких правок, если в будущем что-то поменяется, то возможно и в описании метки нужно будет поменять.

Кто-нибудь это сделает. А если нет, то возможно полное описание такой метки никто и не читает вовсе.

Хотя, если подумать в целом, описание метки должно служить другой цели. Список версий и на офф сайте можно посмотреть, как по мне.

Запрещать такие правки не стоит. Но я бы, всё же, рекомендовал не захламлять описание меток такими длинными списками версий.

Answer (score 3):

В общей схеме на SO ссылки не приветствуются, если на самом SO нет в достаточном объёме нужной информации. Если номера версий считаются такой информацией, то ей вполне себе место на сайте в описании метки. Собственно, в чём смысл, скажем запрещать вносить такие данные в метку? Жалко +2 репы для тех, кто не набрал ещё 20К, или лень проверять такую правку в очереди? С репой, я думаю, вряд ли жалко. Ну а с очередью - не уверен, пропусти! Всё как обычно.